# Setting z to 0 in constrained (on x & y) differential?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Let $w = zxe^y + xe^z + ye^z$ with constraint $x^2y + y^2x = 1$. Assuming x is the independent variable, find $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$.  -  MIT's multivariable calculus course

We can take the total differential:
$dw = f_xdx + f_ydy + f_zdx$

Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in $g(x,y) = x^2y + y^2x = 1$ using $dg = 0$ (since it lies on the level surface $g(x,y) = 1$):

$dg = g_xdx + g_ydy$

$0 = (2xy + y^2)dx + (x^2 + 2yx)dy$

$\frac{-(2xy + y^2)}{(x^2 + 2yx)}dx = dy$

Returning to the equation we would like to find the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$, we have:

$dw = (ze^y + e^z)dx + (zxe^y + e^z)dy + (xe^y + xe^z + ye^z)dz$

And we can write dy in terms of dx (from our constraint):

$dw = (ze^y + e^z)dx + (zxe^y + e^z)\frac{-(2xy + y^2)}{(x^2 + 2yx)}dx + (xe^y + xe^z + ye^z)dz$

**And now we arrive at the step in the answer key which I do not fully grasp**; in particular, the solution replaces all $z$s with $0s$ in the first two terms:

$dw = (0e^y + e^0)dx + (0xe^y + e^0)\frac{-(2xy + y^2)}{(x^2 + 2yx)}dx + (xe^y + xe^z + ye^z)dz$

I understand (x,y) and z are independent, but the partial derivative $w_x$ clearly depends on z. In particular, we can rewrite our constraint $g(x,y) = g(x,y,z) = g(x,y) = x^2y + y^2x + 0z = 1$ so that z can take on any value. Since z taking on any value does not violate the constraint, and assuming $x_0,y_0$ satisfy the constraint, $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} |_{<x_0,y_0,0>} \neq \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}|_{<x_0,y_0,1>}$.

So why do the solutions only consider the point <x,y,0> in computing $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$?

Sources:

[1] [Problem formulation (see #3)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/resources/mit18_02sc_pb_42_quest/)

[2] [Solution (see #3)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/eae43e99915ca70c4545b1e4d694dbbd_MIT18_02SC_pb_42_comb.pdf)

Comment: Good first question

Comment: I'm supposing they want it on the plane z=0

Comment: As written the solution made the mistake most freshman make taking the course. Given that $z$ is the other independent variable $dz$ is set to $0$, not $z$